# Why am I receiving the following error: "struct.error: required argument is not an integer"

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, kali-linux

Attempting to create a script to send beacon frames at 100ms intervals indefinitely. I've had luck with other scripts that include less Dot11Elt sublayers, but for some reason it doesn't like the same 'sendp' command in this script.

```
    ht_caps = Dot11Elt(ID='HTCapabilities', info=(b"\x2c\x19\x03\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"))
```

When I try to execute, I receive the following error:

```
           File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 151, in addfield
      return s + self.struct.pack(self.i2m(pkt, val))
  struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Any ideas what's up?

Edit: it definitely appears as though the issue is with the ht_caps line because I do not receive the same error if I remove it.

Comment: What is the minimum amount of code you need to get the same error?

Comment: The issue appears to be in the 'ht_caps' line. If I comment out everything below that, it seems to work. Is there something about how that line is written that needs to be an integer?

Comment: Please [edit] the code in the question to be such a [mre].

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I fear i'm experiencing a similar problem

Answer (score -1):

The issue stands in this line:

```py
tim = Dot11Elt(ID='TIM', len=(b"\x04"), info=(b"\x00\x02\x01\x00"))
```

You need to pass the length as an integer:

```py
>>> tim = Dot11Elt(ID='TIM', len=4, info=(b"\x00\x02\x01\x00"))
>>> bytes(tim)
b'\x05\x04\x00\x02\x01\x00'
```

You could as well not pass a length, since Scapy re-calculates it automatically:

```py
>>> tim = Dot11Elt(ID='TIM', info=(b"\x00\x02\x01\x00"))
>>> raw(tim)
b'\x05\x04\x00\x02\x01\x00'
```